# MYSQL Selecting the Joined table and Still Shows The UnJoined Rows If ID is the same

Tags: mysql

I am joining a table for a BID application.
I have two tables `BIDS` and `ORDERS`.(I also have Bidders Table for People whocan bid)
This is just a sample of the tables:
ORDERS TABLE:

---

```
OrderID | Item  | OrderStatus|
________|_______|____________|
    1   |Shoes  | On-Bidding |
    2   |Bag    | On-Bidding |
    3   |Shirt  | On-Bidding |
```

BIDS TABLE:

```
__________________________________________________
BidID | BidCost | BidStatus |BidderID  |OrderID  |
______|_________|___________|__________|_________|
  1   | $100    |Waiting    | 2        |2        |
  2   | $200    |Waiting    | 1        |2        |
```

What I want to have is to show the bidder what he can bid for and his bids on the same time for a specific bidder.
For example:

For Bidder ID 2:

```
Order ID| Item  | BidCost |
2       |Bag    | $100    |
1       |Shoes  | NULL    |
3       |Shirt  | NULL    |
```

For Bidder ID 1

```
Order ID| Item  | BidCost |
2       |Bag    | $200    |
1       |Shoes  | NULL    |
3       |Shirt  | NULL    |
```

For Bidder ID 3(He didn't Bid Anything)

```
Order ID| Item  | BidCost |
2       |Bag    | NULL    |
1       |Shoes  | NULL    |
3       |Shirt  | NULL    |
```

What I am having right now is when someone bid for a specific item, the BidCost of another users shows to another user. The I used UNION for all the NULL values but it also shows an order even though you already BID on it Like

```
Order ID| Item  | BidCost |
2       |Bag    | $100    |
1       |Shoes  | NULL    |
3       |Shirt  | NULL    |
2       |Bag    | NULL    |
```

Comment: What does your query look like ?

Comment: @quemeraisc Well it has a lot of columns. I just narrowed it down. But using that it maybe looking like I used UNION between the joined table and the others that return null.

Comment: @quemeraisc the first one looks like this: SELECT * FROM workorder LEFT JOIN bid ON workorder.WONumber=bid.WONumber  WHERE bid.BidStatus='Selected' AND (bid.AutoServiceID=? OR bid.AutoServiceID IS NULL). But if someone bid for an item. Then the item will not show to other Bidders for them to bid.

Comment: I've added your query to the question so it's easier for everybody to read and understand (at least I think so). The query seems to use different names compared to what you tell us of your table, it's a bit confusing.